# two textbox comparer mvcgrid javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

sorry for my english. I am newbie in javascript and MVC. and this is my first post in the great StackOverflow,
Please, can you help me??

i do a Grid like that:

```
@model  IEnumerable<DalcoEF_MVC.Models.Estado>
@using GridMvc.Html
<body>
 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.Nombre ).Titled("IdPrd").Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.NombreEstado).Titled("Estado");
                        columns.Add(c => c.Cantidad).Titled("Cantidad");
                        columns.Add()
                          .Encoded(false)
                          .Sanitized(false)
                          .SetWidth(30)
                          .RenderValueAs(o => '@<input type="text" class="mygridtxt" />).Titled ("Cantidad Enviada");
                        }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
    </div>
    <button id="btn">Out text values</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                $('.mygridtxt').each(function () {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                });
            });
        });
   </script>
</body>
```

But, i can´t do a validation of the column CantidadEnviada (with class = mygridtxt) with the column named "Cantidad"... 
All code of jquery or JavaScript that i could see ask the Id of the textbox or class, but in Grid.MVC I don´t know what name is assigned to this textbox.

Because my english is poor i will put an example:

║idPrd║Cantidad║CantidadEnviada
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

║ 1   ║    30  ║5_->here must be an inputBox->Its Ok ,is less

║ 2   ║    20  ║23->here must be an inputBox->not ok, greater

║ 3   ║    15  ║__->here must be an inputBox-> empty, do nothing
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

when the user set this values, the javaScript must comprarer with the column Cantidad (quantity or stock in english) and if ok, store the id (value in the first column) and on submit, pass all ids that was storage in the array...